# Error:Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am having a problem with the password reset . Its works perfectly if i delete the namespace `app_name = 'crm'` . But when i include `app_name = 'crm'` i get the error,

Error: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

But I want it to work without removing the namespace.

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'crm'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='dashboard'),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
         name="reset_password"),
    path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
         name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
         name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

Comment: Since you use `app_name = 'crm'`, the view should be `crm:password_reset_confirm`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry I am new to django ,so what you are saying is to pass `crm:password_reset_confirm` inside as_view() ?

Comment: can you show the full traceback? Where do you get the error?

Comment: Internal Server Error: /reset_password/
Traceback (most recent call last):
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: when i enter the email address and submit I get this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specified an `app_name = 'crm'`, it means the name of the views should be preced with `app_name:`, so here for example `crm:password_reset_confirm`.

The urls are written in the views, but we can override these, for example with:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'crm'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='dashboard'),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path(
        'reset_password/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('crm:password_reset_done')),
        name='reset_password'
    ),
    path(
        'reset_password_sent/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('crm:password_reset_complete')),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    path(
        'reset_password_complete/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete'
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.2.5 and Python 3.8.10 - same error

In my case, I had to define an email_template_name for PasswordResetView, and recreate that email template.

```
# ...
path(
    'reset_password/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        success_url=reverse_lazy('crm:password_reset_done'),
        email_template_name='my_email.html'
    ),
    name='reset_password'
),
# ...
```